# Creating a C executable to run a installer

Tags: c

I'm looking to do a mass update on a large number of computers and would like to create a simple script that i can just click and run to complete the work much quicker.

I've never tackled anything like this before so im not really sure where to start.

The goal of the script is to take the files which i will be moving from a drive to each laptop, open cmd.exe execute a command and then run the installer that is generated from it. Any advice or pointers on where i can start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but take a look at Powershell scripts - looks like it would be 'easier'.

Comment: One other possibility would be to not reinvent the wheel but instead spend some time learning the use of one of the many tools which can do this.. powershell with Chocolatey, Powershell DSC, Saltstack, Ansible, Otter, ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so --

As other users have mentioned powershell would be a better alternative to C. Or you could use a batch file.

```
@echo off
XCOPY <source path> <destination path> /f /-y
start <your program.exe>
```

When copying it would display the locations it's copying to and from(/f), as well as as for confirmation for overwrites(/-y).

More switches can be seen [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) for the copy command.

Comment: A simple batch (.bat) file could be enough. +1. When seeing the (portable) drive in file manager, run the batch file; the "current directory" will be the one containing the batch, so the letter assigned to the drive is not important (well, drive letters should be avoid).